# How to work with symbolic links to directories

Tags: directory, symlink, cd-command, cwd

I am experimenting with symbolic links and I'm encountering a couple issues.  The first is how after following a symbolic link to a directory to display the actual working directory instead of the directory with respect to the symbolic link (when using `pwd`, for instance).  The second is how to "back up" into the actual directory in the file system instead of backing into the symbolic link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man pwd` on my Ubuntu:

> your shell may have its own version of pwd

I use `bash`. Simple `pwd` command gives me a path with respect to the symbolic link; yet `/bin/pwd` returns the actual path. The `cd` command is also a bash builtin.

In other words: this is shell specific.

**EDIT: thrig's comment (see below) seems to be a better alternative to everything I wrote below this line.**

To "back up" into the actual directory try `cd "$(/bin/pwd)/.."` or `cd "$(/bin/pwd)"; cd ..`. The second form may be tweaked to build an alias to `cd`, I think:

```
alias cd='cd "$(/bin/pwd)"; cd'
```

In the similar way you can get rid of bash `pwd` builtin:

```
alias pwd=`/bin/pwd`
```

Comment: The `bash` option `set -o physical` is relevant here.

Comment: @thrig Make it an answer and get credit. Your way seems to be the right way.

Comment: This is very interesting.  Can you explain what's going on with `pwd`?  I would expect it to have the same behavior as `/bin/pwd`.

Comment: Also, am I mistaken or does `set -o physical` handle the `pwd` issue too?

Comment: My shell (bash) has `pwd` builtin which has precedence over `/bin/pwd` binary. The binary is never executed by `pwd` command, because the shell does all the work by itself and does it its own way. After `set -o physical` the way is somewhat different.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I didn't know that.  So when we type `which pwd`, it doesn't necessarily tell us the program that will run when we type `pwd`?

Comment: @dsaxton Correct. See: shell builtin commands, shell aliases, shell functions.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is `pwd -P`.

From `man pwd` on CentOS 6:

> ```
>    -L, --logical
>           use PWD from environment, even if it contains symlinks
>
>    -P, --physical
>           avoid all symlinks
> ```

Or, from the BSD `pwd` man page and slightly more helpfully worded:

> ```
>  -L      Display the logical current working directory.
>
>  -P      Display the physical current working directory (all symbolic
>          links resolved).
> ```

---

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "back up," but assuming you mean "Change directories into the parent of the current directory," you can use:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(pwd -P)")"
```

Which is equivalent to `cd ..` if your current working path includes no symlinks.

Alternatively, you could use `cd "$(pwd -P)"` to go to the physical path of the current logical directory, and then use `cd ..` as desired.